# What is the best way of testing million concurrent requests?

Tags: linux, docker, node.js, stress

I have currently set up a Docker Swarm that has containers with node.js servers running in it. I am going to try different setups with different amount of node.js containers and see how long it takes to upload json data to servers. My purpose is to a cluster that can handle some stress.

I want to test million concurrent requests and see how server performs. I have currently tried tool called ab (Apache Benchmark) but it was not possible to create million connections with it. I also tried tool called siege but got following:

```
[fatal] unable to allocate memory for 1000000 simulated browser: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What would you recommend me to use with this? Also is there something special I need to take into account in design side?

Comment: A single test system won't be sufficient to generate that kind of load. Investigate distributed testing tools such as 
 https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf or https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns